# Excel IF and or value range

Tags: excel, if-statement, range

I have a formula that currently works pretty well for the most part.  It originally was a scoring factor of  90%-100= 5, and 85% to 89.99% = 4 and 80% to 84.99% = 3 and so on.  This is represented using the formula below:

```
=IF($B10>=90%,5,IF($B10>=85%,4,IF($B10>=80%,3,IF($B10>=75%,2,IF($B10<=74.99%,1)))))
```

So the new requirement came down as follows:

[Range value picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvkOv.png)

```
95  to 100% = 5
85 to 89.99%  or 101.1 to 105%  = 4
80 to 89.99% or 105.1 to 110%   = 3
75 to 79.99% or 110.1 to 115%   = 2
Less than 74.9   = 1
```

So the dilemma I'm in is I have not been able to figure out how to create a range for values 2, 3 and 4 to be either or side for the scoring value to become true.  So score value 4 should be the ranges of 85% through 89.99% OR 101.1% through 105% to be true.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to restructure this to include the ranges so that if either range is true it would show the correct scoring values?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of nested ifs consider using a table then use a VLOOKUP to find the correct value:

I created this table:

[image]

Then I can use this formula to get the proper score:

```
=VLOOKUP(B10,E:F,2,TRUE)
```

[image]

This method has the advantage of being able to easily expand to accomadate new rules.  The only caveat is that your table must be sorted on the first column to get the proper return.

Comment: Thanks so much for this.  That worked perfectly.  Out of curiosity, what does the "2" value do in that formula just before the TRUE statement?

Comment: It pulls the second column as the return value.

Comment: Thanks for the info.